# batch script: compare string evaluates to false

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a script which takes a parameter.

this is a sample from the script:

```
SET application=%1
```

`if (%application%=="prod") (echo "production") else (echo "staging")`

i run the script like that `script.bat prod`

but `staging` is printed to the screen and not `production`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the first line and try `If /I "%~1"=="prod" (Echo "production") Else Echo "staging"`

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your variable with quotes : " (and remove superfluous () around the condition)

```
if "%application%"=="prod" (echo "production") else (echo "staging")
```